# VBA to sort table and ignore total row

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have the range `Table3` as shown below:

[image]

The rows are not fixed and could increase or decrease, I have thus created it as a table `Table3` to accommodate this behavior and also so I could use it in a VBA as a `ListObjects`.

The VBA below is meant to sort the table, however because the `Totals` is part of the range, the sort doesn't work as intended.

```
Sub sort()

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Project 2013").ListObjects("Table3").sort.SortFields _
        .Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Project 2013").ListObjects("Table3").sort.SortFields _
        .Add Key:=Range("Table3[Description3]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _
        xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Project 2013").ListObjects("Table3").sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Can someone please help modify the code to ignore the `Totals` row (i.e to include only the range below the `header` and above the `Totals` row) before applying the sort

**EDIT**

At the moment, this is my attempt at redefining a new range without the last row

```
Sub sort()

Dim resizedTable As ListObject
Set resizedTable = Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")
With resizedTable
.Resize .Range.Resize(.Range.Rows.Count - 1, .Range.Columns.Count)
End With


    resizedTable.sort.SortFields.Clear
    resizedTable.sort.SortFields _
        .Add Key:=Range("resizedTable[Description]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _
        xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
   
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply

End Sub
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Just make the range one row shorter, and then sort. Use the Range method of the Range object.

Comment: I'd try using an actual Excel table, which has built-in totals. Then record a macro that does the sort.

Comment: @DougGlancy Thanks, but for a number of reasons that wont work

Comment: And yet your edit says it is a table/ListObject.

Comment: @DougGlancy - I defined a table range in excel but another application inserts the table data and the (sub)totals totals, I unchecked the Excel-Table options that inserts subtotals because of this - as far as Excel is concerned, the table has no (sub)total.

Comment: Ok, then my answer probably won't work. Let me know in a comment to it, and I'll see if I can come up with something else.

Comment: So, are the inserted totals the last row in the table/ListObject, or are they one row below the last row in the table, or something else. Also, are you sure you can't modify it to just use the table's total feature?

Comment: @DougGlancy I cant modify it to use `Table`'s total feature and yes, the inserted "Totals" row is always the last row in the table

Answer (score 1):

Set a new range for your table, just one row shorter » `totalRowCount - 1`.
Here, `x` is your input range

```
Set x = Range(x.Cells(1, 1), x.Cells(x.Rows.Count - 1, x.Columns.Count))
```

or use the *resize* method

```
Sub CutOffLastLine()
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Project 2013").ListObjects("Table3")
        .Resize .Range.Resize(.Range.Rows.Count - 1, .Range.Columns.Count)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim resizedTable As ListObject`
`Set resizedTable3 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Project 2013").ListObjects("Table1")`

    `With ResizedTable`
        `.Resize .Range.Resize(.Range.Rows.Count - 1, .Range.Columns.Count)` I tried the above similar to your suggestion but I think I have inserted it in the wrong order. I'll try again

Comment: I guess you found the resize method at the same time :)